# How to create a dll in Visual C++ which has a dialog box in it (Dll for Windows applications)

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2015, mfc, modal-dialog

I would like to create a dll which has included a resource (Dialog box - from CDialogEx) - what is the project type in Visual C++ I have to choose?

- How I have to define the entry point? and where should I write the statement

  CMyDialog dlg;
  dlg.DoModal();

Afterwords, I have to use the above created dll in a Windows application. What is the Visual C++ project type I have to choose?

the dll can be loaded using Add->references in the client.
How to call that function which creates the dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build so called MFC Extension DLL. I'd suggest using VS wizard to create a MFC Extension DLL skeleton project.

An MFC extension DLL is a DLL that typically implements reusable classes derived from existing Microsoft Foundation Class Library classes. Only MFC executables (either applications or regular DLLs) that are built with the shared version of MFC can use an extension DLL.

Read this article to find out more: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1btd5ea3.aspx